# Simple IF argument in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I had a function like this:

```
function checker() {
  var newconfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('configs/' + config_pair + '.json'));
  if (JSON.stringify(newconfig) !== JSON.stringify(config)) restart()
  setTimeout(function() {checker();}, 3000);
}
```

I wanted to adjust it and to add 2 more conditions (if the file is new and other 2 parameters are false => run the function:

```
function checker(){
  var newconfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('configs/' + config_pair + '.json'));
  if ((JSON.stringify(newconfig) !== JSON.stringify(config)) && (ignorebid = false) && (ignoreask = false)) restart()
  setTimeout(function() {checker();}, 3000);
}
```

But, now it stopped updating even though paramters `ignorebid and ignoreask are set to false.`

Comment: Note that instead of `ignoreask` you've got `ignroeask`.

Comment: Thank you! I've corrected it, still doesn't work though.

Comment: You are checking the condition to false or assigning values?

Comment: shouldn't you be using '==' or '===' instead of single '='?

Comment: Your if makes no sense since you assign false = instead of comparing with false ==

Comment: `ignoreask = false` is just false. use `!ignoreask` or `ignoreask === false`

Comment: Thank you guys, you rock! I am bad at JS and its' syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to test equality of two values, you have to use a double equal sign `==` (or triple equal sign `===`, if you want to check for type equality, too), because a single equal sign `=` *assigns* a value to a variable instead of comparing. This should work:

```js
function checker() {
  var newconfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('configs/' + config_pair + '.json'));
  
  if ((JSON.stringify(newconfig) !== JSON.stringify(config)) && (ignorebid === false) && (ignoreask === false)) {
    restart();
  }
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      checker();
    },
  3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you wanted to add two more conditions but you actually are assigning the values `false` to `ignorebid` and `ignoreask`

your code should look like,

```
function checker(){
  var newconfig=JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('configs/'+config_pair+'.json'));
  if((JSON.stringify(newconfig)!==JSON.stringify(config)) && (ignorebid===false) && (ignoreask===false)) restart()
  setTimeout(function(){checker();},3000);
}
```